# Edittext is not showing cursor on toolbar

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to implement search feature for my App. To start I am adding EditText to my Toolbar. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/searchproduct"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textColor="@color/whitetext"
        android:textColorHint="@color/whitetext"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Including the toolbar in search.xml layout.

When I open the app. The cursor on Edittext is not seen or softkey don't come. The same code if I put without toolbar. Things are fine.

I got the soft keyboard to come up automatically by giving:

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

But couldn't get the cursor? Is this know issue of cursor and keyboard not showing up automatically on a Editext attached to toolbar?

Can somebody help me fix this issue? I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Thanks!

Comment: It could be that your `colorPrimary` and `colorAccent` has the same color that edittext supply cursor color from the colorAccent.

Comment: colorprimary is green colorAccent is white

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from EditText declaration

```
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
```

It works fine

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with you,and I just change the `colorAccent` different from the `colorPrimary`,It's works.